# initializing views when using instantiateInitialViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

Kind of new to storyboards...

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    MyViewController* myVC = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    //myVC.someLabel.text = @"hi there"; //this doesn't work


    [self pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];

    myVC.someLabel.text = @"hi there"; //this doesn't work either
```

The problem is that myVC.someLabel is nil, even though it's hooked up properly as an IBOutlet. Where/when can I set properties when instantiating a vc via storyboard?

Comment: Does it work on `MyViewController` `viewDidLoad` method? Try to put `self.someLabel.text=@"hi there";`

Comment: Yes it does, so the outlet is hooked up properly. It's a matter of the view not being initialized yet I guess. But how is this usually handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't work because the view of myVC hasn't been loaded at the time you try to access the label. You shouldn't try to do this anyway -- let myVC take care of its own label: you shouldn't set its text from another controller. Instead, pass a string to a string property you create in myVC, and set the text of the label in myVC's viewDidLoad method.